# return array value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to return an array from PHP and in success when I print it it says undefined. How can I get the value of array?

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test2.php",   
      data : {      
                  price : [101, 69, 51],        
                  id : [1, 2, 3]    
},
      success: function(response) { 

         alert response[0];
      }
})
```

//PHP

```
echo $_REQUEST["price"];
```

Comment: `echo $_REQUEST["price"];` will probably result in the output `Array`, since this is the default string representation of arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo json_encode(...);` to encode it in a way jQuery understands. Then `response` is an array just like in your PHP code.

Comment: I have written as echo json_encode($_REQUEST["price"]); but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
price : '[101, 69, 51]'
```

And in client side parse response to JSON:

```
alert( JSON.parse(response)[0] )
```